# improve efficiency of a nested loop

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops, coding-efficiency

I need to find the number of pairs with consecutive numbers in a list. If elements in the list are repeated, they should be treated as members of a distinct pair. For instance, if the list were [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 8], then there are three ways to choose 1 and two ways to choose 2, or a total of  3×2=63×2=6  ways to choose the pair (1, 2), so that the answer would, in this case, be 6.

My solution currently contains a nested loop as below. The code works but I want to optimize for a runtime of less than 2 seconds.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to improve the runtime of this solution?

```
L = [1, 2, 5, 8]
count = 0
for i in range(0,len(L)-1):
        for x in range(i+1, len(L)):
            if L[x] == L[i] + 1 or L[x] == L[i] -1 : 
                count+=1
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail/examples? I'm having trouble understanding the exact goal you wish to accomplish. Are you seeking just to count the combinations for all items (which would include your 6 for the pair 1,2) or are you just wanting specific pairs?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Counter class from collection to classify and count the available numbers, then sum up the product of counts for existing pairs of consecutive values:

```
from collections import Counter

L = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 8]

counts = Counter(L)
r = sum(c*counts[n+1] for n,c in counts.items())

print(r) # 6
```

Comment: this is perfect!! this logic is so much cleaner and simple!